# How to modify \question and \part environment on a new line in Exam Class

Tags: macros, vertical-alignment, texstudio, exam

I am trying to understand Exam Class on LaTeX. So far the documentation has been helpful however I don't know how to modify the structure of \question \part and subparts in a that I want.

This is what I have so far.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\renewcommand\questionlabel{\textbf{Question \thequestion}}
\marksnotpoints
\pointformat{\textbf{\thepoints}} 
\pointsdroppedatright
\pointsinrightmargin


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[1] Why is there air? This should start on a new line and aligned with the question.

\question
\begin{parts}
\part[2] Why is there water? This should also start on a new line and algined with the question.

\part[3] Why is there smoke?This should also start on a new line and algined with the question.
\end{parts}

\question
\begin{parts}
    \part Consider the following sentence “Blah Blah Blah”.
    \begin{subparts}
        \subpart[4] Prove “Blah Blah Blah” is true.
    \end{subparts}


\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

This is the output I get.
[image: My output]

This is the output I want.
[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [exam](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) class provides a `\qformat` command that does most of what you want (see section 4.4 of the manual}. Adding

```
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion\hfill\thepoints}}
```

puts the question number and marks on a line by itself. There is a `\questionhook` command that you can then use to pull the part numbers back to the left hand margin:

```
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}
```

With these in place, the marks overlap slightly with the question text, which you can fix with:

```
\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{5mm}
```

Taken together this produces:

[image]

This does almost everything you want, except that the mark on the question line is not flush with the right margin. My understanding of the manual is that it should be... Apart from this, you probably will want to fine tune the page margins.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\marksnotpoints
\pointformat{\quad\textbf{\thepoints}}
\pointsdroppedatright
\pointsinrightmargin
\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{5mm}
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion\hfill\thepoints}}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{questions}
    \question[1] Why is there air? This should start on a new line and aligned with the question.

    \question
    \begin{parts}
    \part[2] Why is there water? This should also start on a new line and algined with the question.

    \part[3] Why is there smoke?This should also start on a new line and algined with the question.
    \end{parts}

    \question
    \begin{parts}
        \part Consider the following sentence “Blah Blah Blah”.
        \begin{subparts}
            \subpart[4] Prove “Blah Blah Blah” is true.
        \end{subparts}
    \end{parts}

  \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I will look into qformat and paper geometry,

Comment: @AlanJones The placement of the marks seems to be a little off to me.  In addition to the `1 mark` for the question being too far to the left the alignment of the `4 marks` for the subpart is also slightly too far to the left. Offhand I can't see a way to fix these.